# Check if iframe is loaded inside $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if iframe is loaded with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#iframeID').ready(somefunction);
}
```

It seems that 'somefunction' is called before iframe is loaded (the iframe is empty - just empty html-head-body).

Any idea why this happens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
$('#iframeID').load(function() {
    callback(this);
});
```

While dealing with iFrames, it is good enough to use `load()` event instead of `$(document).ready()` event.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're checking if the iFrame is ready, not the document inside.

```
$(document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document).ready(someFunction);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Is it possible to access the document this way now?

Comment: some sites prevent you from accessing their DOM using javascript from inside a iframe, but if the iframe is on the same domain you should be able to manipulate the DOM using `document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document` to get the document

Answer (score 0):

I have tried:

```
$("#frameName").ready(function() {
    // Write you frame on load javascript code here
} );
```

and it did not work for me.

this did:

```
$("#frameName").load( function() {
     //code goes here
} );
```

Even though the event does not fire as quickly - it waits until images and css have loaded also.